# Android priority job queue error while serializing object

Tags: android, serialization

Trying to understand how to work with this lib.
Use example from twitter examples:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration.Builder(this)
        .minConsumerCount(1)
        .maxConsumerCount(3)
        .loadFactor(3)
        .consumerKeepAlive(120)
        .build();
jobManager = new JobManager(this, configuration);
jobManager.addJob(new simpleJob("simple text"));

class simpleJob extends Job{
    private String text;
    public simpleJob(String text) {
        super(new Params(1000).requireNetwork().persist());
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdded() {
        Log.i("job", "onAdded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        Log.i("job", "onRun");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancel() {
        Log.i("job", "onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable throwable, int runCount,
                                                     int maxRunCount) {
        Log.i("job", "shouldReRunOnThrowable");

        return RetryConstraint.RETRY;
    }
}
```

In console i see only "onAdded". "onRun" never happened. If i add log interceptor, i see error text "error while serializing object simpleJob".
What is it? What object should be serializable?

Comment: did placing the job in a separate class work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i explore, serializetion does not work if job is inner class. You need to place your job in separate class.